# Inno setup page order

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup which can perform 4 types of installation types

- Full install
- Server install
- Client install
- Custom install

When installing the client App i don't want to place files on the local machine but
connect the client with the server installation.
The user has in this case not to chose a destination for the installation but has to chose a directory where a server installation is already installed. 
It would be less confusing for the user if he would first select the installation type and then the installation directory or the server directory.
Is there any way to perform a switch in the page order ?

I am thinking about something like this:
[image]

i am aware that this behavior is something that isn't directly build in inno setup and maybe not wished but it would be very helpfull for the user.
Maybe somebody has a different approach on this problem, i would appreciate that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i haven't got an answer for this problem and i don't think that it is possible to change the order ,i disabled the DirPage in the Setup section and created a Page that does the same as the DirPage but put it at a different position in the Setup.

Here is how to disable the DirPage:

```
[Setup]
...
DisableDirPage=yes
```

I still would be happy if anyone has a more elegant solution, but so far it seems to be the only one.

Comment: I would say this solution is the most elegant at this time since all the other ways would introduce ugly hacks. It's not easy (if even possible) to change the page order.

Comment: You wrote: "I put it at a different position". How can I establish a page position? In my setup I have 4 custom pages and I can't understand how to define their order. Thanks.

Comment: @jacktric The Comment section is not suitable to answer this question. Would you mind to create a question on SO :) ? If you post a link to the question in this comment section I will give you a short answer.

Comment: @Bongo thanks for your tip but I found the solution in the meantime.

Comment: @jacktric Would be nice if you could post the link to that info. I've been looking hours for it - looks to be creation order but cannot find anything definitive. Guess I'll have to post a question - but if it's already here I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Ok I finally figured out how to control the order.
Create the custom page you want first to display and use the INNO page constant when calling the Createxxx method.
After that, then you create them using the ID of the page you previously created (assuming they are all in the range between the INNO page constant you first used).