# How can I do this in Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I have a function **Check('Path')** that checks if I'm trying to install my program into **Path** and if it returns 1 I have to move from the `Select Destination Location` page to a page like this:

[image]

If I press `<Back` then I have to return to the `Select Destination Location` page. And if I press `Cancel` then I need to show another window like this:

[image]

If I press `Continue` the window disappears and if I press `Cancel` the Installer closes.

Comment: Anyway, have you seen [Skipping custom pages based on optional components in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13921535/850848) or [How to skip custom page based on setup type in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58559285/850848)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl But I don't need to skip custom page here. I need to show the standard page after my page that's taken its place. I added some code to my question.

Comment: *"I need to show the standard page after my page that's taken its place"* – What standard page? You haven't told us anything about any page that should go after your custom page.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have 2 parts of my program and they can't be installed into the same folder. So when I'm on the SelectDirPage I check if the path is correct. Depending on the result I need to go to my custom page (the first screenshot in my question).

Comment: You can't change the order of the default pages. You can choose to ignore default pages based on conditions etc. I wonder if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422285/inno-setup-page-order

Comment: @JConstantine Your comment does not answer my question. To be more specific, please answer these (in the question, not in comments) – 1) When do you want go to your custom page? And when not? 2) What do you want to do in the cases you do not want to go to your custom page? 3) Where do you go to after the custom page?